# iOS localized keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I need to make the keyboard in my app to appear on a specific locale, without the user having to go to the settings menu on the phone. I know is simple for the user to select a language via the localization keyboard button, but for the design of the app, it has to be done automatically, without user interaction.

I've found out the next bit of code, that helps me to perform such a task.
My question is, if this code is valid for Apple or they will reject it, and what side effects could you think about this, if any. I couldn't find any problem so far.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ko", nil] forKey: @"AppleLanguages"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own keyboard and make it display instead. This is probably better than overwriting the system. Look up writing custom keyboards

Comment: Actually, I ended going this path, and I wrote my own keyboard, which wasn't that difficult.